# When I SUM values of each month between 2 dates, I get the wrong value

Tags: sql-server, date

I am really struggling with a query. I want the sum of each month between Aug 2014 and July 2015. If I specify the between dates in the where clause it sums all the months.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @CurrentYear int = DATEpart(year,getdate()) 
DECLARE @PreviousYear int = DATEpart(year,getdate()) -1
SELECT  
SUM(CASE WHEN a.fin_period = concat(@PreviousYear,'08') THEN a.balance ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceAug ,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.fin_period = concat(@PreviousYear,'09') THEN a.balance ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceSep ,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.fin_period = concat(@PreviousYear,'10') THEN a.balance ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceOct ,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.fin_period = concat(@PreviousYear,'11') THEN a.balance ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceNov ,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.fin_period = concat(@PreviousYear,'12') THEN a.balance ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceDec ,
...etc.
FROM subaccount_history a with (nolock) 
WHERE fin_period between concat(@PreviousYear,'08') and concat(@CurrentYear,'12')
```

The issue is with the between clause, i tried group by but that also doesn't work. It sums everything between the 2 dates specified.

Comment: Almost all of the actual query uses `@PreviousYear` but then, suddenly in the `WHERE`, `@CurrentYear` reappears. Is that the problem?

Comment: In the following dates it uses @currentyear because it runs from last year August to this year July. I did not add those months to save space, they are where etc. is.

Comment: Which sum is incorrect? That one month displays a larger balance, or that you want to keep the detail records with all balances next to them? Could you perhaps post an example of the current result versus the expected result? Thanks.  (Oh, and can you include your version of sql server? The Pivot function could really make life easier for you here, and/or window functions, depending on your needs)

Comment: SQL Server 2012. The result set is fine but when I tested the data I saw that it is not correct. For example: if it take one month for testing, select sum((CASE WHEN a.fin_period = 201412 THEN a.balance ELSE 0 END) AS BalanceDec) from subaccount_history where fin_period = 201412 the result is 8296011.45 but when I run it with the where fin_period between x and y I get this result: 167104326.47

Comment: Shouldn't this, "concat(@CurrentYear,'12')" be "concat(@CurrentYear,'07')"?

Comment: that was just an example. it should sum all balances for august 2014, sum all for september2014, sum all for november 2014 etc.. until july 2015. and then in the overall where clause between august 2014 and july 2015. But I get the wrong results

Comment: Can't see any reason why the results using between would differ, the sql looks ok. Could be changed to pivot, but should work as is. The between could return more rows if fin_period could contain long values such as 20140810, but those would still not be included in the case clause. For clarity: what types are used? fin_period is an integer or varchar field? There are no joins that are left out for the example code?

Comment: Hi Guys, thank you very much for your help. I figured it out. There is a join I left out so it returned more values than necessary. Just shows you, the smallest detail is important in queries :/